# Fiddler how to set up to listen to microsoft excel odata feed dala loading loading url

Tags: excel, odata, fiddler

I want to load data in to an excel file using Microsoft Excel Get Data from OData Feed. 
To trouble shoot an issue I have to analyze the requests of localhost and test server request data loading service calls.

Could some one help me out with explaining **how to set up Fiddler to listen to the web service calls sent via MS Excels OData feed.** 
Many thanks.

[image: get data fron odata feed]
[image: odata feed url]

Comment: Fiddler excludes by default localhost/loopback traffic. If you want to capture it anyway you have to enable it in Options -> Connections.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I found the way. I edited the script to capture it.